# interfacing ht12d decoder to PIC microcontroller?

Tags: embedded, microcontroller, pic, interrupt-handling, mikroc

this is my first question here. 
i have ht12d ic connected to pic16f84a.. VT pin connected to Rb0/int pin of pic.. and the 4 data lines are connected to 4 pins of PortB.. also am having a digital sensor also connected to rb0/int pin.. whenever there is interrupt either from the decoder ic or the sensor i ve managed to deal with these two sources of interrupts.. the problem is ht12d pins remains latched to last signal and don't return to default state.. in fact am using the status of these 4 pins to differentiate between the two interrupts.. for example :
proto:

```
if portb.b1 is 1 then its command 1;

if  portb.b2 is 1 then its command2;
if  portb.b3 is 1 then its command3;
if  portb.b4 is 1  then its command4;
```

if they are all 0, then it's sensor interrupt ;
is there any way to reset ht12d data pins to default state after each valid transmission..

Comment: From HT12D datasheets: _The output of the VT pin is high only when the transmission is valid. Otherwise it is always low_

Comment: Maybe your interrupt on RB port could be set on rising edge.